# Analytic family of operators?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

If $E_{\lambda}, F_{\lambda}$ are two families of complex Hilbert spaces and $L_{\lambda} : E_{\lambda} \rightarrow F_{\lambda}$ is a family of bounded linear operators, where $\lambda$ is a complex parameter, what does it mean, precisely, to say that $L_{\lambda}$ is an analytic family of operators?

My problem is with the domains and codomains changing. How does one make sense of this?

Is it easier if $E = E_{\lambda}$ for all $\lambda$?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a definition given, for instance, [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02788866).

Comment: @Mike true, but the operators defined there are of a rather special form. They map functions on a measure space to functions on another measure space. I wouldn't know how to identify my Hilbert spaces with some $L^2$ since I have a whole family of them.

Comment: Every separable Hilbert space is isomorphic to $L^2(\Bbb R)$, if that's any good for you. What context does this come from?

Comment: @Mike I'm aware of the result you mention, but again, I have a whole family of Hilbert spaces and can't see a way to choose for each $\lambda$ an isomorphism to some $L^2$. I don't think some crazy choice function would be a reasonable thing to do here. Here's an example of this situation: the (derivatives of the) exponential map of a Hilbert manifold along a curve.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'm still not sure where you encounter the phrase, though... That would help for giving a coherent definition.